# Run multiple queries then display them based on weighted importance like Facebook Wall

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am building a social network site for a client and one of things that has been troubling me is how I am going to display status updates, new blog posts, profile comments etc. on their "wall". The problem is not querying the database and displaying the information... it is displaying all the information within 1 query. For example, lets say I have the following tables:

```
Members, 
MemberComment, 
Statuses, 
Articles
```

I know I can display member statuses in one query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM status WHERE who = '$profileid' ORDER BY ID DESC
```

And then I can display comments like this:

```
SELECT * FROM member_comments WHERE which = '$profileid' ORDER BY ID DESC
```

I am using while loops to display each section of data, one while loop for the comments, one for statuses, and so on.

How can I display this information in a way where it is sorted by date posted, or level of importance? I don't know how to condense all the queries into one, and then on top of that, be able to display it the right way in a while loop.

Comment: I dare say you are going to have to JOIN some tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up going with, and it works fine for now. It returns both comments and statuses and orders them by date posted...

```
    SELECT
    member_comments.what AS commentWHAT,
    member_comments.who AS commentWHO,
    member_comments.when AS commentWHEN,
    members.name AS commentNAME
    FROM member_comments, members
    WHERE member_comments.who = members.id AND 
    member_comments.which = '$id'
    UNION
    SELECT
    status.what AS statusWHAT,
    status.who AS statusWHO,
    status.when AS statusWHEN,
    members.name AS statusNAME
    FROM status, members
    WHERE status.who = '$id' AND members.id = '$id'
    ORDER BY commentWHEN DESC
```

Then I echo out the data as follows:

```
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $message = $row['commentWHAT'];
            $commentWHO = $row['commentWHO'];
            $commentNAME = $row['commentNAME'];
            $statusWHO = $row['statusWHO'];

            echo '
            <div class="fairway_thing">
                <img src="images/avatar-60.jpg">
                <p><strong><a href=profile.php?uid=' . $commentWHO . '>' . $commentNAME .'</a></strong> ' . $message . '</p>
                <p><a href="#">Like</a> <a href="#">Tweet</a> <a href="#">Share</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            ';
```

Answer (score 0):

One example for member status

```
select member.*, status.* from member m
  inner join status s on m.member_id = s.who 
order by s.ID desc limit 1
```

Comment: Using joins.. How would I display the data? Using mysql_fetch_array and a while loop? Or something different?

Comment: you still get a row back like normal. In this case, due to the `limit 1` you'll only get one result. When in doubt, run the query manually and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, I would use the GROUP_CONCAT function to get all your children and put them into one row for the parent in a new column. Then you can parse that field on your server side to show each result individually.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some kind of similarity between the various tables, and some kind of idea about how to deal with relevance, you could use the UNION  operator. It's like magic!

Sample query:

```
select title, 
    date, 
    100 as importance
from memberComment
where originalPostMemberID = $currentUserID
union
select title, 
  date, 
  1000 as importance
from statuses
where (some way of working out visibility of the status request)
union 
select title, 
  date, 
  1010 as importance
from articles
where (some way of working out visibility of the status request)
order by date desc, importance
```

Comment: So you can order by multiple perameters? IE data AND importance?

Comment: Yes, you can. Union only works if all your queries return identical columns, so that's a limitation - but if you can use union, you can order by more than one column.

Comment: What is an alternative solution to union? I have been expirementing with it and I feel I may run into trouble further down the road since I need identical columns...

Comment: Firstly, there are some benefits from keeping the columns identical - you don't have to modify your client-side code to behave differently for each type of item - or at least, you only have to modify presentation logic, not have the client know that a "status" has a "date" field and an "article" has a "tags" field. However, if you want to avoid union in this way, you can use group_concat (as per Juventus18's reply). Alternatively, you could go for parent child - one query to retrieve the wall items as per the above, then specific queries to retrieve the items for the wall.